# Package 'upstart' has no installation candidate

Tags: debian, upstart

When I try to install upstart on Debian 9, I get :

```
# apt-get install upstart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package upstart is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  systemd-sysv sysvinit-core

E: Package 'upstart' has no installation candidate
```

[Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Upstart) states that:

> Installation is quite simple. The only package necessary is upstart.

My sources list:

```
###### Debian Main Repos
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free
```

How can I fix this error and install upstart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upstart was abandoned by its developers when Ubuntu switched to systemd, and was [removed from Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=808289) before the release of Debian 9.

The [supported init systems in Debian 9](https://wiki.debian.org/Init) are systemd, `sysvinit` and (to a far lesser extent) [Runit](https://wiki.debian.org/runit), `file-rc` and `openrc`. If you want to use systemd (which is the default), make sure the `systemd` and `systemd-sysv` packages are installed; to use `sysvinit`, install `initscripts`, `sysv-rc` and `sysvinit-core`.

I recommend against attempting to use Upstart, it had a number of release-critical bugs when it was removed.

Comment: I've deleted my previous answer, because this one explains nicely why it was removed, possible replacements, why not to use it, and because the person answering clearly understands how to use the packages, unlike me :).